# Using PrepareCall method to pass a parm to a function and to return a count Value

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlexception, callable-statement

I wrote a function in Oracle, which takes a parm and return a count.
The stored procedure's return type is number.
I call the function using PrepareCall method in Java as,

```
public static int checkPreviousLoad(int Id) { 
    int countPrev = 0; 
    //Here we run the Function to get the existing count of to be loaded Id.         try { 
        CallableStatement proc_stmt = connection.prepareCall(" {? = call F_CHK_PREVIOUSLOAD(?)}"); 
        proc_stmt.setLong(1, Id); 
        // Register the type of the return value             proc_stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER); 
        // Execute and retrieve the returned value.             proc_stmt.execute(); 
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) proc_stmt.getObject(1); 
        rs.next(); 
        countPrev = rs.getInt(1); 
        System.out.println("the count is: "+countPrev); 
        rs.close(); 
        proc_stmt.close(); 
    } catch(SQLException e) { 
        String temp = e.getMessage(); 
        System.out 
                .println("ERROR: SQL Exception when executing F_CHK_PREVIOUSLOAD \n"); 
        System.err.println("ERROR MESSAGE IS: " + temp); 
        System.err.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState()); 
    } 

    return countPrev; 
}`
```

This is throwing an SQLException.

Error Message is like this: 
ERROR: SQL Exception when executing F_CHK_PREVIOUSLOAD

ERROR MESSAGE IS: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2 
SQLState: null

Please tell me where I went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The error you're receiving is because you have commented out the necessary [`registerOutParameter() method of`CallableStatement`interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter(int,%20int)) , that registers the output parameter with its corresponding type.
2. Also, change the input parameter to 2(as it is argument number 2 in the prepared statement).

And, please don't call your stored procedure a function.

Perform the following changes before storing the results in ResultSet :-

```
CallableStatement proc_stmt = connection.prepareCall(" {? = call F_CHK_PREVIOUSLOAD(?)}");     
proc_stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
proc_stmt.setLong(2, Id); 
proc_stmt.execute();
//  ... your succeeding code
```

Comment: Sir,  i made the necessary changes. Now I get this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet  for this line of code, ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) proc_stmt.getObject(1);

Comment: The return value of the Store Procedure is a a count value.

Comment: @user2015-And talking about this new error, these lines are not correct-->`ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) proc_stmt.getObject(1); 
        rs.next(); `. Instead, you should directly use **countPrev=proc_stmt.getInt(1)** instead. If you still face errors, I suggest you to search on the internet to how to resolve the error